# TEvent or TLightweightEvent do not work in Android service (Delphi-Berlin)

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2.

`TEvent` and `TLightweightEvent` do not work in an Android service.

Any of these calls will not return:

- `Event1.SetEvent;`
- `Event1.WaitFor(100); // should return after 100 ms`

Only this one returns:

- `Event1.ResetEvent;`

My Android service `OnCreate` event contains:

```
Event1 := TLightweightEvent.Create;  // or TEvent.Create;
```

When doing the same thing in the main app, all works fine.

Unfortunately, logcat does not show any errors, either.

Has anyone experience the same issue, or know a solution?

Comment: Submit a bug report

Comment: @David: See [RSP-16525](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16525)